# compare current month and year with timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

How to compare month and year only from timestamp? my timestamp formate in mysql is like this

```
2015-02-15 15:00:09
```

What will be the sql to get row on specific month and year?
I use DATE to compare current date with timestamp.

```
$q="SELECT * FROM products WHERE DATE(time) = CURDATE()";
```

Now how to compare current month year with my timestamp? 
I searched here but didnt find any clear answer. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$q="SELECT * FROM products WHERE MONTH(time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) and YEAR(time) = YEAR(CURDATE)";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

If the column Time is indexed, then this is the efficient method

```
$q="SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE time >date_add(current_date,interval - day(current_date) day) and
Time<date_add(date_add(current_date,interval - day(current_date)+1 day),interval 1 month)"
```